# Error setting classpath

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests

I want to run an automated test-case generation tool on the class Realm.java of project Async-HTTP-Client.

I located its path:

```
[dario@bob async-http-client]$ find /home/dario/async/553/prefix -name Realm.java
/home/dario/async/553/prefix/async-http-client/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/Realm.java
```

Hence set the classpath to:

```
[dario@bob async-http-client]$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/dario/async/553/prefix/async-http-client/api/src/main/java:/home/dario/async/553/prefix/async-http-client/evosuite-tests:/home/dario/testEnv/684131/prefix/rhino/lib/xbean.jar:/home/dario/evosuite/target/evosuite-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-minimal.jar
```

But when I run the command to generate tests:

```
[dario@bob async-http-client]$ ~/evosuite/target/bin/EvoSuite -class org.asynchttpclient.Realm -projectCP /home/dario/async/553/prefix/async-http-client/api/src/main/java:/home/dario/testEnv/684131/prefix/rhino/lib/xbean.jar
* EvoSuite 0.1-SNAPSHOT
* Unknown class: org.asynchttpclient.Realm
```

I am told the class is non-existent.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as Google revealed EvoSuit needs the compiled class.

My guess is that you eighter didn't compile the class or it landed in a different directory.